# Using Firebase to Login on Serverside

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an web app and a nodejs server.

Its easy to login client-side with Firebase to google or another provider.
But, I want to login via my nodejs server.

Client -> Request to Server -> Firebase -> Google -> Redirect -> Server -> Client

So my goal is to get the 302 Redirect through my server to the client.
Is this possible ?

Comment: No Ideas anyone ?

Comment: Ok, i switched to passportjs and implemented some provider there